# With Delphi/Pascal there are internal methods - isn't there a way of doing that in C#

Tags: c#

A long time ago I used to code in Delphi/Pascal, and a very nice feature was to be able to declare a procedure as internal to another procedure.  I can't remember the syntax, but it meant you could have code all in the "same" place and not have declare the inner procedure somewhere else in your code.

Is there a way to achieve something like that in C#?

Comment: The discussion around the "Method Within A Method" provides a number of useful answers.  I obviously didn't use the correct key words when asking the question. :)

Comment: It doesn't address the Pascal angle, iow only the enclosing of functions, not accessing parent variable and parameter frames from inner functions.